# Num lock problems with Dell keyboard and system

Tags: windows, keyboard, numlock

I just purchased the keyboard "Dell Wired Keyboard KB216 (580-ADMT)" from Amazon to replace another Dell keyboard in which the num lock function stopped working properly without apparent reason. I need to be able to use the keypad numbers to type special characters with the help of the ALT key. The OS I'm using is Windows 10 Home. Many web posts suggest modifying the registry, but I've tried three different numbers in InitialKeyboardIndicators without success. When I boot up and immediately open Notepad, I am able to use Alt+XXXX shortcuts for about 30 seconds, then it stops allowing me to type symbols using this method. What is going on? We suspect the issue might have been caused by a recent Windows update, but I welcome any advice I can get. Thank you!